# setState is not changing the initial state

Tags: react-native

I am doing react-native-modal where user clicks and see different car models and then picks one. In `onPress` in `Touchableopacity` I pass the id the a function and then use `setSelectedCarModelID`.

The id is passed from touchbleopacity to the function and it gets printed but when I use `setSelectedCarModelID` it doesn't update the state.

```
// this is where I initiated the state
const [selectedCarModelID, setSelectedCarModelID] = useState(null);


// the function that is supposed to handle state update
const changeSelectedCarModelId = (id) => {
    console.log(id, ":: id")
    setSelectedCarModelID(id)
  }
// 
 <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => {
                              changeSelectedCarModelId(carModel.id);
                              console.log(selectedCarModelID, ' id :: ' ,carModel.id);
                            }}
                            key={carModel.id.toString()}
                            style={{ width: 50, height: 80 }}
                          >
```

Comment: Is it printed in the `onPress` handler and the `changeSelectedCarModelId`? Would you mind sharing the component in its entirety?

Comment: It is very long, I shared the important parts, setting the initial state, passing the id to a function is working, but to update this state is not working.

Comment: onPress shows only the initial state and the state doesn't get updated

Comment: @tarekhassan, where you use the setSelectedCarModelID

Comment: I use ```setSelectedCarModelID``` inside the function ```changeSelectedCarModelId```, I did that because I couldn't update from onPress

Comment: whats being priointed in console.log od id?

Answer (score 0):

how about this? usualy i use the constructor to initiated the state

```
// this is where I initiated the state
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    selectedCarModelID: null, 
    setSelectedCarModelID: null
  };
}
// the function that is supposed to handle state update
const changeSelectedCarModelId = (id) => {
  console.log(id, ":: id")
  // setSelectedCarModelID(id)
  this.setState({ setSelectedCarModelID: id})
}
// 
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    changeSelectedCarModelId(carModel.id);
  }}
  key={carModel.id.toString()}
  style={{ width: 50, height: 80 }}
>
```

Comment: He's using a functional component with hooks API. This appears to be functionally the same.